# Compare nested object with the separate array and check if the values of object is match then update value of key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have following data which contains the one nested object and second with compare array as shown following.

```js
let nestedObj =  {
   one: {
      "one data": [ 
        { id: "One+0", count: "1" },
        { id: "One+1", count: "2" },
        ]
   },
   two: {
      "two data": [
        { id: "TWO+0", count: "2" },
        { id: "TWO+1", count: "2" },
        { id: "TWO+2", count: "2" }
      ],
    },
    three: {
      "three data": [ 
        { id: "Three+0", count: "1" },
        { id: "Three+1", count: "2" },]
        }
 }
 
 checkArr= ['TWO+0','TWO+1']
```

So my requirement is to iterate the nestedObj and compare with the checkArr.
So if the values are found inside nestedObj so in this case TWO+0 and TWO+1 will be find then it will update those values inside nestedObj like **TWO+0 with TWO+updated** and **TWO+1 with TWO+update**.

Thanks.

Comment: What have your tried so far ? Would you mind adding your attempts of `code` to solve these requirements you have ?

Comment: Sure!!! I will edit the post what I have been tried so far.

Comment: But first, please [look for an existing solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+find+nested+by+value+site:stackoverflow.com)